# How to stop a for loop inside an ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, executorservice

I've tried looking on other threads and I can't seem to find a proper answer,

When using executorService.shutdownNow() almost all tasks stop immediately as intended except ones with for loops in them.
I have no idea why it happens, but the most I've seen from other threads is that you should be using Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() to check if it is interrupted, but adding a

```
if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
    {return;}
```

Doesn't actually stop it all.  I'm calling executor shutdownNow when a UI button is toggled off.

Code example:

```
executorService.submit(() -> {
            ctx.batzUtils.keyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, VK_SHIFT);
            //Shit keeps going if you call ShutdownNow Todo
            for (Rectangle rect : rects)
            {
                ctx.batzUtils.click(rect);
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(minDelayBetween, maxDelayBetween);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ctx.batzUtils.keyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, VK_SHIFT);
            ctx.batzUtils.keyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, VK_SHIFT);
        });
```

Any ideas as to why or solutions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Add `interrupt()` in the exception block and try.

Comment: @Batzpup Once thread is running state,   executor shutdownNow() will not stop running thread, you need  to check in your task logic whether this thread is interrupt or not.
If it is interrupted then you need to make sure that some how it should complete the task.
In your case, if it is interrupted then break the for loop so that task will complete.

Comment: When `shutdownNow()` interrupts your thread, `Thead.sleep()` will throw `InterruptedException`. Since you ignore that exception, the loop will just continue.

Comment: Thank you guys for commenting, @Sambit answer worked so ill mark that as a solved,
But the other comments helped me understand why the code wasn't working, so again thanks

Comment: If shutdownNow was called, add `return` to the catch block will also bail out of the processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 solutions. your for loop you do need to check 
`if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {[clean up and finish the thread code here]}`

In your `catch` section, instead of `e.printStackTrace();` place [clean up and finish the thread code]. In the catch statement you don't need to check if the thread has been interrupted. The fact that you caught the InterruptedException is already a flag that the thread has been interrupted

Answer (score 0):

Adding  Thread.currentThread().interrupt() in my catch statement worked

Credit To @Sambit

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> When using executorService.shutdownNow() almost all tasks stop immediately as intended except ones with for loops in them.

This is a misleading statement. `executorService.shutdownNow()` cancels any jobs that have not run yet and interrupts all of the threads that are currently running.  The reason why some of your threads aren't being interrupted is because you are catching `InterruptedException` in your for loop.  Whenever `InterruptedException` is thrown, the interrupt bit of the running thread is cleared.

Whenever you catch `InterruptedException`, you should immediately re-interrupt the running thread so that the caller will know that the interrupt has been set.  Your bug is a good example of why this pattern is necessary.

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(minDelayBetween, maxDelayBetween);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // when InterruptedException is thrown it clears the interrupt bit so
   // we need to re-interrupt the thread whenever we catch it
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   // you should handle the interrupt appropriately and not just print it
   return;
}
```

Here's a good tutorial on the subject of [Java thread interrupts](https://www.baeldung.com/java-interrupted-exception).